# OpenFeint Android : unable to initialise OF sample. "feint requires an active network connection" appear on the screen

Tags: android, openfeint

I am trying to run openfeint android sample on Android 2.2 to verify its functionality. I am sure that I have enter product keys, etc, correctly. I have two problems:

1> message appear at bottom "feint requires an active network connection".(Am sure my internet connection is fine)

2>sometime openfeint loading page appear and automatically disappear itself without showing page one which asking for user permission.(and this happen frequently)

Please advice how can i solve above problems.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

-You'll need an active internet connection obviously with the following permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

-Thats interesting. When do you want to connect to OpenFeint? I strongly suggest that you should call it after you load etc the main menu. But without further information, it's hard to find out.

Comment: Thanks for replying. OpenFeint sample already have internet permission by default. I have check AndroidManifest.xml file, its there. Please let me know if you have any more idea regarding the issue.

Comment: I want to connect immediately after intro video of my game end. But right now am much interested to see the sample of OF project given on OF website run properly.